# SQL Building Pathway using With Union in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

**This is SQL Server Question**

I have a set of categories, and their relationship results in nested categories.

I want to build a pathway keeping the relationship and build the SEF urls. Here is what I am looking for:

```
Category table: 
ID, Name
1, Root
2, Cat1
3, Cat2
4, Cat1.1
5, Cat1.2
6, Cat2.1
7, Cat2,2

CategoryChild table: ParentCategoryID, ChildCategoryID
1, 2
1, 3
2, 4
2, 5
3, 6
3, 7
```

It is an unlimited nested structure. Here is what I am doing (I know its wrong but want something like this):

```
WITH  MenuItems
    AS (

        SELECT  

        CAST((ItemPath) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS 'ItemPath',
        CategoryID, Category, ChildID
        FROM    #Mapping
        WHERE   CategoryID = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
                CAST((items.ItemPath + '-/' + MenuItem.Category) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS 'ItemPath',
                MenuItem.CategoryID, MenuItem.Category, MenuItem.ChildID
        FROM     #Mapping AS MenuItem
                JOIN MenuItems AS items
                  ON items.ChildID = MenuItem.CategoryID 
       ) 
select * from MenuItems
```

It gives me something like this:

```
root--------|1---|root---|2
root--------|1---|root---|3
root/Cat2---|3---|Cat2---|6
root/Cat2---|3---|Cat2---|7
root/Cat1---|2---|Cat1---|4
root/Cat1---|2---|Cat1---|5
```

So ideally the path should be like this:

root/parent/child (and so on)!

Comment: You forgot the RECURSIVE keyword?

Comment: What database are you using?  If you are using SQL Server, you want recursive CTEs.  If you are using Oracle, you want connect with path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I've played with recursive cte's in the past and so this might be helpful in building the items path.

NOTE: I've included additional information like the Root Id and Level for each item, so that you can change the ordering of the output.

```
declare @Category table (Id int, Name varchar(10))
insert into @Category values (1, 'Root'),(2, 'Cat1'), (3, 'Cat2'), (4, 'Cat1.1'), (5, 'Cat1.2'), (6, 'Cat2.1'), (7, 'Cat2.2')

declare @CategoryChild table (ParentCategoryID int, ChildCategoryID int)
insert into @CategoryChild values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)

;with cte as 
(
    -- root part
    select 
        ccParent.ChildCategoryID Id,
        ccParent.ParentCategoryID ParentId,
        c.Name Name,
        CAST(parentCategory.Name + '/' + c.Name as varchar(1000)) as Path,
        ccParent.ChildCategoryID Root,
        0 as Level
    from
        @CategoryChild ccParent
    inner join
        @Category c on c.Id = ccParent.ChildCategoryID
    inner join
        @Category parentCategory on parentCategory.Id = ccParent.ParentCategoryID
    where
        ccParent.ParentCategoryID = 1

    union all

    -- recursive part
    select
        ccChild.ChildCategoryID Id,
        ccChild.ParentCategoryID ParentId,
        c.Name Name,
        CAST((cte.Path + '/' + c.Name) as varchar(1000)) as Path,
        cte.Root Root,
        cte.Level + 1 as Level
    from
        @CategoryChild ccChild
    inner join
        @Category c on c.Id = ccChild.ChildCategoryID
    inner join
        cte on cte.Id = ccChild.ParentCategoryID
)
select cte.Path 
from cte 
order by cte.Root, cte.Level
```

Running the above within my environment gives the following results

```
Root/Cat1
Root/Cat1/Cat1.1
Root/Cat1/Cat1.2
Root/Cat2
Root/Cat2/Cat2.1
Root/Cat2/Cat2.2
```

If you were looking to include the Root category in your result set as a standalone item then you can change the first part of the cte to hard code the select of the root item.

```
;with cte as 
(
    -- root part
    select 
        c.Id Id,
        null ParentId,
        c.Name Name,
        CAST(c.Name as varchar(1000)) as Path,
        c.Id Root,
        0 as Level
    from
        @Category c
    where 
        c.Name = 'Root'

    union all

    ... same as before
```

Giving the follow

```
Root
Root/Cat1
Root/Cat1/Cat1.1
Root/Cat1/Cat1.2
Root/Cat2
Root/Cat2/Cat2.1
Root/Cat2/Cat2.2
```

Comment: Hmmm so hardcoding the root cat with 'Null ParentID' gaves an error, telling the column types for ParentID dont match across the 'union all' so i just did this 'CAST(0 as bigint)  as ParentID' so it works fine. (I am using BigInt type for ID columns), so guys must keep column types in mind when doing such stuff. Good Luck!